# Increase z-index of child

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to make a child's div higher than the parent's. Is there a way to do so?

```
<div class="main_wrapper" style="position:relative; margin-top:-3rem; padding: 3rem, 4rem; z-index:-1;">
   <div class="child" >
     here I created a box that has a z-index of -1 since it inherited it. 
     Can I change it to higher than the main_wrapper?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read the duplicate until the end to find tricks using 3D transform

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set z index in the css, and you can use selectors to help impact what you need to. for this instance, you could do the following:

[Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

main_wrapper > div { z-index: 1 }

or if you are going to give the child elements classes you might as well use it to set the z index.

.class { z-indez: 1 }

either way id move all the html inline styling to the class, as it's a better practice to keep styling outside of the template in most cases

Comment: Hey @iamaword,
thanks for your reply. Please bear in mind that I didn't use inline style - I just  wanted to make the question look neat here, also giving the child div a z -index of 1 or higher number doesn't bring it out of the main div that has the z-index of -1.

is there some other way to try?